# membership proof

Tags: isabelle, proof

I need to prove the following:

```
lemma  "m = min_list(x#xs) ⟹ m ∈ set (x#xs)"
```

In plain English, I need to prove that the return value from "min_list (x#xs)" is always a member of (x#xs)

I tried:

```
apply(induct xs)
apply(auto)
```

I also tried to reuse existing lemmas for the min_list by using:

```
find_theorems min_list
```

The sub-goal at this point is so long that I do not know how to proceed.

**I am not looking for a full answer just hints on how to approach this lemma.** Moreover, is this proof an easy one or significantly difficult one for someone just learning Isabelle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spoiler: it is possible to use the standard list induction and `auto` to prove the theorem, i.e. something similar to `by (induct xs ...) (auto simp: ...)`. I deliberately left out sections in the proof for you to fill in on your own. You will need to think about if any variables (i.e. `m` or `x`) need to be specified as `arbitrary` and also understand what information the simplifier may need (look for clues in the specification of `min_list` in the theory `List`).

With regard to your question about the difficulty of the problem, I believe, that difficulty is a function of experience. Most certainly, when I started learning Isabelle, I was finding it difficult to formalise proofs similar to the one in your question. After a certain time spent coding in `Isabelle` (by the time of answering this question, I must have accrued an equivalent of 4-5 months of full-time coding in `Isabelle`), such problems no longer seem to present a significant challenge for me. Of course, there are other factors that need to be taken into account, e.g. previous training in mathematics or logic and previous coding experience.

---

*General advice from someone who is learning Isabelle on his own (the advice may not be consistent with the approach that is normally recommended by professional instructors)*

I believe, when proving similar results, it is important to understand that Isabelle is, primarily, a tool for formalisation of 'pen-and-paper' proofs. Therefore, it is important to have the 'pen-and-paper' proof at hand before trying to formalise it. I would suggest the following general approach when attacking similar problems:

1. Write the proof on paper.
2. Formalise the proof using `Isar`, providing as many details as possible and not caring too much about the length of the proof. Also, try not to rely on the tools for automated reasoning (i.e. `auto`, `blast`, `meson`, `metis`, `fastforce`) and use direct methods like `rule` and `intro` as much as you can.
3. Once your `Isar` proof is complete, apply tools for automated reasoning (e.g. `auto`, `blast`) to your Isar proof to simplify your proof as much as possible.

Of course, eventually, it will become increasingly easy to omit 1 and 2 as you make progress in learning Isabelle.

I can provide further details, e.g. the complete short proof and the long `Isar` version of the proof.

---

**UPDATE**

As per your request in the comments, I provide an informal proof.

**Lemma**. `m = min_list (x # xs) ⟹ m ∈ set (x # xs)`.

**Remarks**. For completeness, I also provide the definition of `min_list` and some comments about the const `set`. The definition of `min_list` can be found in the theory `List`:

```
fun min_list :: "'a::ord list ⇒ 'a" where
"min_list (x # xs) = (case xs of [] ⇒ x | _ ⇒ min x (min_list xs))"
```

The const `set` is defined implicitly and constitutes a part of the `datatype` infrastructure for `list` (see the document "Defining (Co)datatypes and Primitively (Co)recursive Functions in Isabelle/HOL" in the standard documentation if Isabelle). In particular, it is called the 'set function' of the datatype. Many basic properties of the const `set` can be found by inspection/search, e.g. `find_theorems list.set`. I believe that the theorem `thm list.set` is representative of the main properties of the const `set` (I took the liberty to rename the schematic variables in the theorem):

```
set [] = {}
set (?x # ?xs) = insert ?x (set ?xs)
```

**Proof**. The proof is by structural induction on the list `xs`. The induction principle is stated as an unnamed lemma at the beginning of the theory `List`. For completeness, I restate the induction principle below:

`"P [] ⟹ (⋀a list. P list ⟹ P (a # list)) ⟹ P list"`

*Base case*: assume `xs = []`, show `m = min_list (x # xs) ⟹ m ∈ set (x # xs)` for all `x`. From the definition of `min_list`, it is trivial to see that `min_list (x # []) = x`. Similarly, `set (x # []) = {x}` can be shown directly from the properties of the const `set`. Substituting into the predicate above, it remains to show that `m = x ⟹ m ∈ {x}` for all `x`. This follows from basic set theory.

*Inductive step*: assume `⋀x. m = min_list (x # xs) ⟹ m ∈ set (x # xs)`, show `m = min_list (a # x # xs) ⟹ m ∈ set (a # x # xs)` for all `a`, `x` and `xs`. Fix `a`, `x` and `xs`. Assume `m = min_list (a # x # xs)`. Then it remains to show that `m ∈ set (a # x # xs)`. Given `m = min_list (a # x # xs)`, from the definition of `min_list`, it is easy to infer that either `m = a` or `m = min_list (x # xs)`. Consider these cases explicitly:

- Case I: `m = a`. `a ∈ set (a # x # xs)` follows from the definitions. Then, `m ∈ set (a # x # xs)` by substitution.
- Case II: `m = min_list (x # xs)`. Then, from the assumption `⋀x. m = min_list (x # xs) ⟹ m ∈ set (x # xs)` it follows that `m ∈ set (x # xs)`. Thus, `m ∈ set (a # x # xs)` follows from the properties of `set`.

In all possible cases `m ∈ set (a # x # xs)`, which is what was required to prove.

Thus, the proof is concluded.

**Concluding thoughts**. Try converting this informal proof to an `Isar` proof. Also, please note that the proof may not be ideal - I might make edits to the proof later.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it is extremely useful. Can you maybe share the informal proof? The one that you would write on paper. I hope that can help for inspiration.

Comment: Thank you so much!!